# Meaning of this notation - $T = \bigcup_{B \in \beta}B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

$$T = \bigcup_{B \in \beta}B$$

Does the $B \in \beta$ mean that $T$ is a union of some arbitrary subsets of $\beta$, or does it mean that $T$ is the union of all subsets of $\beta$?

Comment: $T$ is the union of all _elements_ of $\beta$. $\beta$ is a family of sets.

Comment: So what notation would be used when you want to define $T$ as the union of some arbitrary subsets of $\beta$?

Comment: You would need to indicate which subsets you use. A family of subsets of $\beta$ is a subset of the power set, for $F \subset \mathfrak{P}(\beta)$, $$T = \bigcup_{M \in F} M$$ is a union of some subsets of $\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you are familiar with the notations $$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n,\ \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty A_n$$

Both of these take the union of an indexed family, whose index is $\Bbb N$. But we can talk about larger index sets, for example $$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i.$$

In the general context, though, given a family of sets, we can just index it by itself. So what happens if $A_i=i$? Then $$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i=\bigcup_{i\in I}i,$$
and so $\beta$ is a family of set which indexes itself, so $B\in\beta$ is both the index and the set.